# How to implement FCM in android app? Is it possible that we can use same listener, receiver methods of GCM with FCM?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

Hi I would like to migrate from the `GCM` to `FCM`.

I would like to know that,
shall I use the `IntentService`, `GcmListenerService`(May be `FcmListnerService`) classes of `GCM` with `FCM`?

I have googled for some sample codes but I couldn't get.

Any help will be appreciated..

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the following documentation:

Migrate a GCM Client App for Android to Firebase Cloud Messaging

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm#import_your_gcm_project_as_a_firebase_project

This explains everything needed to migrate from the Manifest, Gradle script changes, and goes all the way to the broadcast receiver.

Comment: Note: you should not use GCM and FCM together, so when migrating it should be a replacement of GCM with FCM.